# Unexpected error in rails controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, controller

I am writing a controller test to test controller actions as follows

```
require './spec/rails_helper'
require './spec/spec_helper'

RSpec.describe WeatherController, type: :controller do
  describe '#query' do
    it 'returns right template' do
      #get 'query_weather'
      #expect(response).to render_template(:query)
    end
  end
end
```

I have nothing in my test. my controller action is empty too.

```
 1) WeatherController#query returns the right template
     Failure/Error: raise TypeError, "#{path.inspect} is not a valid path: must be a String, Pathname, or Resolver"

     TypeError:
       #<RSpec::Rails::ViewRendering::EmptyTemplateResolver::ResolverDecorator:0x00007fffe869b938 @resolver=#<ActionView::FileSystemResolver:0x00007fffe771fe28 @unbound_templates=#<Concurrent::Map:0x00007fffe771fe00 entries=0 default_proc=nil>, @path_parser=#<ActionView::Resolver::PathParser:0x00007fffe771fd88>, @path="/root/apple_weather/app/views">> is not a valid path: must be a String, Pathname, or Resolver
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/actionview-7.1.3/lib/action_view/path_set.rb:79:in `block in typecast'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/actionview-7.1.3/lib/action_view/path_set.rb:68:in `map'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/actionview-7.1.3/lib/action_view/path_set.rb:68:in `typecast'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/actionview-7.1.3/lib/action_view/path_set.rb:19:in `initialize'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/actionview-7.1.3/lib/action_view/view_paths.rb:35:in `new'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/actionview-7.1.3/lib/action_view/view_paths.rb:35:in `_build_view_paths'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/actionview-7.1.3/lib/action_view/view_paths.rb:69:in `view_paths='
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-rails-4.0.1/lib/rspec/rails/view_rendering.rb:153:in `block (2 levels) in <module:ViewRendering>'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `instance_exec'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `instance_exec'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:365:in `run'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:529:in `block in run_owned_hooks_for'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:528:in `each'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:528:in `run_owned_hooks_for'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:615:in `block in run_example_hooks_for'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:614:in `reverse_each'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:614:in `run_example_hooks_for'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:484:in `run'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:505:in `run_before_example'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:261:in `block in run'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:511:in `block in with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:468:in `block in with_around_example_hooks'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:486:in `block in run'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:626:in `block in run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:352:in `call'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-rails-4.0.1/lib/rspec/rails/example/controller_example_group.rb:191:in `block (2 levels) in <module:ControllerExampleGroup>'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `instance_exec'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `instance_exec'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:390:in `execute_with'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:628:in `block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:352:in `call'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-rails-4.0.1/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter>'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `instance_exec'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `instance_exec'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:390:in `execute_with'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:628:in `block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:352:in `call'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:629:in `run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:486:in `run'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:468:in `with_around_example_hooks'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:511:in `with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:259:in `run'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:646:in `block in run_examples'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:642:in `map'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:642:in `run_examples'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:607:in `run'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:608:in `block in run'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:608:in `map'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:608:in `run'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:121:in `block (3 levels) in run_specs'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:121:in `map'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:121:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:2070:in `with_suite_hooks'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:116:in `block in run_specs'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:74:in `report'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:115:in `run_specs'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:89:in `run'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rspec-core-3.12.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
     #
     #   Showing full backtrace because every line was filtered out.
     #   See docs for RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_exclusion_patterns and
     #   RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_inclusion_patterns for more information.

Finished in 0.06694 seconds (files took 2.13 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/weather_controller_spec.rb:6 # WeatherController#query returns right template
```

Additional info: Rails version: 7.1.3

It does not specify which line in the code is bombing out in either the controller or test.

I have tried upgrading the rspec.

I have followed the template to create a test.

Comment: Can you post your `routes.rb` and the code of the controller you want to test?

Comment: Probably a callback defined in one of your helper files. Show them

Comment: This is the routes.rb

Answer (score 1):

I have solve this problem.

Update the gems version based on rails 7.1.3

```
gem 'rspec-rails', '6.1.1'

group :test do

  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver

  gem 'capybara', '3.40.0'

  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '4.10'

  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome

  gem 'webdrivers', '5.3.0'

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `render_view` in the controller if you want views to be rendered in controller specs.

So add

`render_view`

just before the describe block